# how to hide the whole table if there is only 1 row

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have example table below, sometime it has content , but sometime doesn't.

How do I use jquery, so that if there is no td (or there is only 1 row of tr) I will hide the whole table?

```
example 1:
<table>
<tr><th>some title</th></tr>
</table>

example 2:
<table>
<tr><th>some title</th></tr>
<tr><td>some content</td></tr>
</table>
```

I tried, but doesn't seem working.

```
$('table').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $(this).remove();
});​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to this:

**js**

```
$('table').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('tr').children("td").length < 1) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4N6WD/5/)

You want to hide your table? If yes i suggest to use `hide()` cause `remove()`, removes the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var len = $('#yourTable tr');
 if(len.length>1){
  $('#yourTable').show();  
 } else {
  $('#yourTable').hide();   
 }
```

Example : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/j9DtG/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).find('td').length < 1 || $(this).find('td').is(':empty') ) {
       $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BX46H/1/